# .htaccess returns 500 for a simple redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have created an app in Laravel.
My initial .htaccess was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it worked properly for the domain api.viglug.org.
After I added the m.forum.viglug.org domain (with the same root directory of api.viglug.org).
At this point was exactly the same to call api.viglug.org and m.forum.viglug.org.
I wanted to use the m.forum.viglug.org for the folder api.viglug.org/mobile so I thought it would have worked with this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m\. [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/mobile/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I was wrong. It keeps returning error 500 if I use m.forum.viglug.org, while api.viglug.org works as expected.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there anything showing in your Apache or PHP error log? Usually when a PHP script gives a 500, it is because there is a fatal error, which will be logged to a file. You could also try temporarily letting errors output to the page, with `ini_set('display_errors', true)`

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m. [NC]` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m\. [NC] `

Comment: @IMSoP: This is what appears in the Apache error.log: [Fri Jan 11 19:10:55 2013] [error] [client 93.33.245.47] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @shawndreck: it gives me exactly the same error as before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original rewrite only runs on files which do not exist as real files or directories, due to these two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Have you tried adding those two conditions above your additional rule?

```
# Mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/mobile/$1 [L]

# Normal site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The 500 error has gone away, but the rewrite rule does not work, since it provides me the index.php page (with no parameters)

Comment: That, I'm afraid, must be down to whatever method Laravel is using to extract and use the pathinfo on the end of index.php. I have no experience of that framework, so can help no further. To check that the rewrite itself is working, try changing the target to a test file, e.g. `test.php?type=mobile&path=$1` and dumping out the `$_GET` array.